# Searching for Duplicates Algorithm Explanation: Why Does This Work?

Tags: python, duplicates

I've been working on coding interview questions to gain a solid understanding of data structures and algorithms (as a recovering copypasta-er). Recently, I was working through search algorigthm problems and solved the following one: search an array for duplicates? The code I used to search an array and find duplicates is:

```
arr=[1, 2, 3, 4, 3];

for i in range(0, len(arr)):
  for j in range(i+1, len(arr)):
    if arr[i]==arr[j]:
      print(arr[j])
```

This then returned

```
3
```

My question is this: why does the line

```
for j in range (i+1, len(arr))
```

work? Why couldn't I use some other range, like

```
for j in range (0, len(arr))
```

or

```
for j in range (i, len(arr))
```

Why does the code I used work and any other code I experiment with give weird results? I was able to get the

```
for j in range (i+1, len(arr))
```

through trial and error, but don't really understand why the code works properly. Thanks!

Comment: Your alternate forms for that loop all have the problem that the range of values that `j` takes includes the value of `i` - in other words, you'll occasionally be comparing a list element to *itself*.  That certainly shouldn't count as a duplicate!

Comment: Do you not understand what the parameters to `range()` mean?  A range starting at `i` includes `i`, a range starting at `i+1` does not include `i`.

Comment: Aaah, gotcha! Thanks!

Comment: One last question, and I think this will clarify my misunderstanding here. If 'i+1' makes sure that the value of 'j' isn't including the value of 'i', why does 'i-1' not do the same? I apologize if the question is a little basic, I'm just trying to make sure I have a total grasp of the fundamentals. Thanks again!

Comment: A range starting with `i-1` will include `i` as its second element (assuming that it has at least two elements).

Comment: Got it! Thanks for humoring me here! Your answers were very helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets step through the code line by line.

- Line 1: is an integer list referenced to arr variable.
- Line 2: Steps though the array/list(arr) one by one beginning from the first element.
  so when i = 0, which is the first word.
- Line 3: steps through the list(arr) but from the second index(i+1). so now j = 1. Remember we are looking for duplicates so we need to pick one item at a time and compare with the rest of the items in the list.
- Line 4: Now if at anytime, i at an index which is a word is same as j which is also a word at the next index,

  Line 5: the print function will execute by printing that word which is the
  duplicate.

Comment: thank you! That makes perfect sense. Thank you for explaining this to me!